# Changing order of data received via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to ajax and jQuery so thank you for your help. I am working with someones code and trying to understand what is going on so I can make a change.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MobileLogin.aspx/GetForemanTimecards",
    data: "{'locJobPhase':" + dailyTCOptions.locationJobPhase + ",'frmn': " + dailyTCOptions.foreman + ",'weekendingDate': " + JSON.stringify(loggedAppUser.CurrentWeekEndingDate) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var fdt = JSON.parse(data.d);
        var listDiv = $('#dailyworkDay');
        $(listDiv).empty();
        $(listDiv).append('<li data-role="list-divider" data-theme="b">Select Work Day</li>');
        $.each(fdt.HrsByDate, function (idx, val) {
            $(listDiv).append('<li id="' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("L") + '" data-theme="b"><a href="#"  id="' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("L") + '"  Data-Transition="slide" style="font-size:0.8em"><label  id="lbl' + val.WeekDate + '" title="' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("L") + '">' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("dddd") + '(' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("L") + ')' + '</label><span class="ui-li-count"  id="sp' + moment(val.WeekDate).format("dddd") + '">' + val.TotalHrs + '</span></a></li>');
        });
        $(listDiv).listview("refresh");
        $(listDiv).children('li').unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
            dailyTCOptions.selectedWeekDay = $(this).context.id;
            var hours = $(this).text().substring($(this).text().indexOf(")") + 1, $(this).text().length);
            $('#SubMenuContainer').popup('open');
            if(hours == 0) {
                $('#ulDailySubMenu li').eq(3).hide();
            } else {
                $('#ulDailySubMenu li').eq(3).show();
            }
        });
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    },
    failure: function (msg) {}
});
```

This is the result:

[image]
I can see that the for each jQuery loop is what is creating the menu:

```
$.each(fdt.HrsByDate, function (idx, val) {
}
```

I can also see that it is looping through the data received from ajax (I think).

So my question is how do I change the format of how the data is received? Specifically, the days are coming in backwards. How can I get the data to be returned from Monday to Sunday low date first?

Comment: What a mess is your code. You could have a look at where the data is coming from. You could do `fdt.reverse()` (if it is an array). Or do `$(listDiv).prepend` instead of `$(listDiv).append`

Comment: if it were me i'd live that mess well alone and try to sort it using the database query

Comment: That's actually what I am looking for. From this code how can I trace where the database query is?

Comment: look for `locJobPhase, frmn and weekendingDate` in `MobileLogin.aspx/GetForemanTimecards`see if you can find the db connection

Comment: Can you show us what the generated HTML looks like?

Comment: For some reason the rendered HTML is not showing in 'View Source' so i took a screenshot of it in developer tools. Here it is: http://i.imgur.com/kMUFaSo.png

Comment: Is it always just a single query with only the one week of data?